# Use Dir.chdir to work with a path name with spaces in it

Tags: ruby, macos

On Mac OSX, using the Ruby `Dir` class, I want to change to a directory that has spaces in it. I have tried:

```
Dir.chdir('/Users/Chris/Library/Application\ Support')
```

but  received the exception

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory
```

How do I do this?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error by using the first line of code. The code works without escaping the whitespace. I'm using BigSur and ruby 2.6.5/3.0.1.

Comment: very strange, it now works. I thought I tested each line in the console before pasting it. I am going to edit the question to remove the ``` Dir.chdir('/Users/Chris/Library/Application Support')``` attempt, and then if you like you can answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Don't Escape Spaces Inside Single Quotes

Don't escape spaces inside single quotes. If you do, the String will contain a literal quote character, which will not match your directory name. Consider:

```
'\ '
#=> "\\ "
```

If you have a space in the name, just use proper quoting without escapes for the spaces. Examples include:

```
Dir.chdir '/Users/Chris/Library/Application Support'
Dir.chdir "/Users/Chris/Library/Application Support"
Dir.chdir %q(/Users/Chris/Library/Application Support)
```

There may be situations where you need escapes inside single quotes (such as escaping a single-quote character, e.g. `'\''`) but your example is not one of them.